Removing All security groups from AD disabled users powershell script
Kind of new at this, but I'm currently trying to delete all groups from disabled users besides the primary group for sub OU.
Currently my domain environment looks like this
-company.example.com (domain) 
 -CompanyName (OU) 
   -Users (OU) >
     -Location 1 (OU)
     -Location 2 (OU)
   ServiceAcct (OU)

Currently my Powershell script is the following
$searchOU = "OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=example,DC=com"
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -SearchBase $searchOU | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
    Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Removing $($_.Name) from $($group.Name)" -Foreground Yellow
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $_ -Confirm:$false #-whatif
    }
}

This runs, but the problem with this is that some disabled users are service accounts and need their security groups, therefore I need to target CompanyName > Users > Location 1 more precisely to avoid messing up service acccounts but when I add the sub OU path (Location 1) and run the following:
$searchOU = 'OU=Location1, OU=Users,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=example,DC=com'
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -SearchBase $searchOU | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
    Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false } | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Removing $($_.Name) from $($group.Name)" -Foreground Yellow
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $_ -Confirm:$false #-whatif
    }
}

Nothing happens and when I run the sub OU alone:
$searchOU = "OU=Location1,DC=company,DC=example,DC=com"
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -SearchBase $searchOU | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
    Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Removing $($_.Name) from $($group.Name)" -Foreground Yellow
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $_ -Confirm:$false #-whatif
    }
}

I get the following error
Get-ADGroup : Directory object not found
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -SearchBase $searchOU | Sort- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFou 
   ndException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

What am I missing in this code to get to the sub OU?

I've used $searchOU = 'OU=Location1, OU=Users,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=example,DC=com' nothing happens when i run it just get back to c:

I've identified in ADUC that in Location1 there are 5 disabled users with several security groups

no the groups are a subfolder OU in CompanyName Ex. Security groups OU path OU=Groups, OU=CompanyName"  and the user OU is 'OU=Location1, OU=Users,OU=CompanyName  How could i edit/add my code to target the security groups in the specific Location1 sub OU

Sorry i'm kind of new to this, I guess i'm not being clear. What i want to do is in ADUC I have ``my.company.com (domain) > companyname (OU which contains all computers/users/other objects) > Users (OU) > Location1 (OU) that contains a specific target of users I want to remove security and distribution groups. My code only is letting me delete from the entire companyname OU but there are other disabled accounts in the entire OU that cannot lose Security/distribution groups.

The overall goal of this project is to go to 'OU=Location1, OU=Users,OU=CompanyName and delete each user that is disabled from every security and distribution group and repeat this process which each Location under the same OU path.

Using GetADUser does not work i tried and got the following error

Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'SearchScope'. Cannot convert value "OU=Location1,OU=Users, OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=example,DC=com" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADSearchScope". Error:  "Unable to match the identifier name OU=Location1,OU=Users, OU=companyName,DC=company,DC=example,DC=com, to a valid  enumerator name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: Base, OneLevel, Subtree" Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $false' -Properties memberOf -SearchScope $searc ..+  + CategoryInfo:InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException+
